# How to programmatically manage startWatch and stopWatch in an AnyLogic model

Tags: anylogic

I'm building a model with AnyLogic using the Process Model Library (PML).

In my network I have 4 "source" elements that emits agents, they are all of the same type but with a different "category" string ID inside them (saved as a variable) to differentiate them; they are purchase order from different departments. I have also inserted blocks to measure the time the agents spend to exit from the assembler elements (you will see in the picture inside the red circles). This is the time that I will want to plot in a graph to show how fast they are.

After some test and reading the documentation I have see that when an agent pass under the start photocell (agent of any department) a timer is activated and the opposite when an agent (agent of any department) pass under the stop photocell the timer is stopped. Also in case of agent with different category IDs.

How can I synchronize the timers to measure time of object with the same category ID? I want that if the first source element "Category Nilo&Salmoni" produce an agent the stopWatch measure the time of this one and not of another one, emitted from another category, that reach the stopwatch first.

[image: Sample of network]

Comment: Anylogic measures the time for a specific agent. From your picture it seems that the objects that enter the start time measurement block are not the same ones that enter the stop time measurement block.

Comment: Yes they are different object; inside the StartWatch enters object of type "IntentionToBuy", instead inside the StopWatch enters object of type "PurchaseOrder". The objects are correlated so to one IntentionToBuy object corresponds a purchaseOrder object and I would like to measure the time (that then I will plot in a chart) that the department use to produce a purchase order since when the relative IntentionToBuy is emitted.

Comment: In that case, I believe that's not the correct approach because the time measurement blocks are meant to measure the time for a specific agent, not two related agents.
To do so, you could use auxiliary collections. You have an ID that relates the two agents so for that ID you store the enter time and the exit time (using time() on the correct blocks) . Then you just need to do exit-enter = time in system.

Comment: Do you have some advice?

Comment: The network you see in picture is inside an agent-type that I'm building. The time() function is accessible as "self.time()"?

Comment: time is the simulation time, which is common to all agents.